# Detect new entries in django model through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Is there a way I can check for new entries through ajax and update the page appending them to a div?

I'm thinking about a situation like this:

```
Client x access the page
Client y post a new entry.
Client z access the page.
```

For client x, it will display a message: `New entry found` and a button that can get that entry.

For client z, everything it's normal, as for client x before client y submitted a new entry.

I haven't figured out how can I do this, actually, I have no idea, so I apologize because I haven't tried anything yet to show you.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: Read this article please: https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django. It shows you how to use `channels` to achieve your goal.

Comment: It's a little bit complicated for just one feature that I need, but it's a good way to handle things for some other projects, thanks for the answer!